# Distribution of high and low of a random walk

Tags: distributions, random-variable, random-walk

If I have a one-dimensional random walk with position $X(\text{t})$ with $X(0)=0$ and $\text{Var}(X(1)) = 1$, 
and I observe $X(1) = \text{c}$, what are the distributions of the minimum and maximum values of x between times 0 and 1 conditional on c, and what is the distribution of the range over this time interval?

Here is why I ask. I want to jointly simulate (min,max,range,final) for a random walk. To simulate the final value alone a normal random number generator can be used.

Comment: You must define your notation better!  Random walk usually refers to discrete time, but your notation seems to indicate continuous time, so that you really are referring to a brownian motion!

Comment: My question is about the maximum and minimum of $X(t)$ between times 0 and 1 in continuous time, conditional on $X(t) = c$.

Comment: You could find the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.3473v1.pdf
useful!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have skimmed the paper. I see that the Wikipedia article on the Wiener process has a formula for the joint distribution of the maximum and final value of a Wiener process.

Comment: Aren't the mins and maxs a function of the assumption wrt an underlying distribution? In other words, if a normal distribution is posited then these would be finite values. If a more extreme valued distribution is assumed then any empirical min or max could be infinite, requiring theoretical infimums and supremums.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: @DJohnson That's not the case for random walks. This question asks a purely theoretical question concerning the joint distribution of $(X(1), M, m)$ where $M$ and $m$ are the maximum and minimum of the walk on the interval $[0,1]$.  They are all almost surely finite, even when the increments are non-normal.

Comment: @whuber  Of course you are right that for random walks defined on a 0,1 interval, they would have finite mins and maxs. However, you seem to be implying that this will hold for *all* random walks. If so, is that correct? In other words, ever since Bachelier the universality associated with random walks and/or Brownian motion has always been closely related to the universality of the Gaussian. Mandelbrot was one of the first to reject those assumptions and suggest that some sort of more extreme valued, power law process was underlying "random" behaviors such as moves in stock price

Comment: @DJohnson Since a random walk is defined to be the sum (or, for continuous processes, the integral) of its increments, the very fact that $X(1)$ is finite implies all intermediate values were finite, too, *regardless of how the increments might have been distributed.*

Comment: @whuber   That's true for this query. I'm trying to establish a different point. So, does your observation generalize to *all* incremental sums (integrals) of *all* random walks? Forgive my ignorance, but to Mandelbrot's comment (to take one example), I'm not aware that it does.

Comment: @DJohnson Yes, my comment is fully general.  According to the rules of arithmetic of extended real numbers, if a sum or integral should ever reach infinity, it must always stay there.  Thus, if by time $1$ it has the finite value $c$, it never could have been infinite at any previous moment.

Comment: @whuber  Apologies for continuing to hammer away at this but I've learned to be very careful on this site regarding the details inherent in people's wording. Are you saying that your comments are "fully general" to random walks defined on the standard unit interval between 0 and 1? Or are you saying that your comments hold for **all** random walks, regardless of whether or not they are defined for a standard unit interval? Thanks.